# Does this regex allows number in top level domain?

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regex example. I'm new to regex.

```
^[a-z0-9](\.?[a-z0-9_-]){0,}@[a-z0-9-]+\.([a-z]{1,6}\.)?[a-z]{2,6}$
```

I'm thinking where is the top level domain here, is it starting on the right or on the left? And what is it?

Comment: Not too sure what your problem seems to be here. Regex works from left to right.

Comment: OP is trying to parse an URL. He wants to get `google.com` from `https://www.google.nl`

Comment: I only see regex here. Not any part of a domain. It's not clear to me what you are asking though. Perhaps it would be better asked like "How can I get the top level domain from a url or email using regex" instead of having us backwards engineer a random regex string to determine which part of that regex can be used to find the top level domain of some string you haven't specified. In other words... What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: It depends what the input string contains. If it contains only an URL, then you can simply search for the [LastIndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netframework-4.7.2) `'.'` without regex.

Comment: @Aars93 pretty sure that RegEx is for emails.

Comment: @Vulpex I want to know what is top level domain. Is my question wrong? How can I improve this? The word "top level domain" is new to me and is used in regex context.

Comment: @RonaldAbellano `top level domain` is the `.com` part in an URL. For example `www.google.com` has the top level domain `.com`. Your regex is checking for validity of an email address.

Comment: Please add examples of possible inputs, the actual results and the desired results.

Comment: @JNevill I just to identiy and know what is TOP LEVEL DOMAIN.  I'am preparing for an exam and got a question if the regex allows number in top level domain. So yeah I need to identify where to start.

Comment: @RonaldAbellano there are plenty regex tester online. Your regex would accept `blah@bah.com` but not `blah@bah.d2`

Comment: I've updated the question title. Sorry for the low quality of the question.

Comment: Got it!. So the question is like "Given this regex, are numbers are allowed in the top level domain". Does it specify what the input string will look like that this regex searches? Like... "Assuming the string being searched is an email address, does this regex allow numbers in the top level domain"?

Comment: have you considered a checker tool like - http://regexstorm.net/tester

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex you've provided won't allow Numbers in top level domains.
`[a-z]{2,6}$` is the part checking the top level domain. It'll only allow lower case characters, minimal 2 characters max 6 characters.

EDIT: Let's deconstrunct your your regex for clearity.
`^[a-z0-9](\.?[a-z0-9_-]){0,}@[a-z0-9-]+\.([a-z]{1,6}\.)?[a-z]{2,6}$`
the `^[a-z0-9](\.?[a-z0-9_-]){0,}` part checks from the beginning of the string if there are only allowed characters that are `a-z`and `0-9` followed by an optional `.` followed by `a-z`and `0-9` aswell as `_` and `-` zero to infinite times.

`@[a-z0-9-]+\.([a-z]{1,6}\.)?` checks for an @ after the first part aswell as validity of the domain, `a-z` and `0-9` including `-` followed by a `.` with an optional `a-z`2 to 6 times, up to one time i.E. `google.com` would be acceptable at this point but the `.com` part is optional.

`[a-z]{2,6}$` checks for `a-z` 2 to 6 times and the end of the string indicated by `$`. meaning this is the part checking for the top level domain.

your regex would accept: `blah@google.com` aswell as `blah@google.com.com`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know "top level domain" is like the domain name I know in web development. I would know if "top level" wasn't there.

Comment: Worth noting there are TLDs longer than 6 characters.

Comment: @RonaldAbellano I've deconstructed your RegEx a little, hope this'll help you understand what your RegEx does. I strongly recommend opening a regex tutorial and a regex testing site to get some practice.